# What is the formula for calculating the number of bits required to encode the number $x$ in Fibonacci coding?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, coding-theory, number-systems

What is the formula for calculating the number of bits required to encode the  number $x$ in Fibonacci coding?


For example:

if $x=1$ then because $1$ in Fibonacci coding is "11" therefore the formula will return $2$,

if $x=2$ then because $2$ in Fobonacci coding is "011" therefore the formula will return $3$,

if $x=10$ then because $10$ in Fibonacci coding is "010011" therefore The formula will return $6$.


Updae:


Thanks to lulu for the link [A130233](http://oeis.org/A130233) which contains some versions of formulas that satisfy the solution. The simplest version of them:
$a\left(n\right)=\left\lfloor\frac{\log_{10}{\left(\sqrt5\cdot n+1.5\right)}}{\log_{10}{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}}}\right\rfloor$

Comment: If I have understood the question, this would appear to be [A130233](http://oeis.org/A130233)

Comment: sorry lulu I responded to your answer. I saw that my responde was wrong and then I deleted it...

Comment: No worries. $\quad$

Comment: In the link there are 5 different formulas for calculating "a(n)". I tried the last one, because it is the simplest. I saw that I was getting correct results. Of course I checked only a small set of numbers. In other numbers, are there differences in the results between the 5 formulas or do they all return the same results and only the way of calculation is different?

Comment: Oh, I would imagine that all the formulas are correct.  OEIS is pretty careful with such things.  If memory serves, I've found typos on the site, but no substantive errors.  None of the formulas look all that hard to derive but, as you have noticed, they aren't exactly simple so it makes sense to present a few variants.

Comment: Thank you very much lulu! Your link contains exactly the formulas I was looking for.